# render custom user control using xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have custom user control. Namespace where this control belong is imported and is added to the window.resources element like

```
<Window
   ...
   xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyPrj.WPF.Views">

<Window.Resources>
   <Views:AddEditData x:Key="AddEditView" />
   ...
```

Question is: how to render this control inside grid or any other panel using xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing it under resource section. **Put that inside some panel** and it will be rendered.

```
<Window xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyPrj.WPF.Views">
   <DockPanel>
      <Views:AddEditData x:Name="AddEditView" />
   </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Or in case you place it under Resource section, you need `ContentControl` to get it render like this:

```
<Window xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyPrj.WPF.Views">
   <Window.Resources>
      <Views:AddEditData x:Key="AddEditView" />
   </Window.Resources>
   <DockPanel>
      <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource AddEditView}"/>
   </DockPanel>
</Window>
```